# How can i setup a Socket.io client on flutter?

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I have a flutter app and i am trying to connect it to a node.js localhost server. it works with react js but I haven't done it in flutter before. can I get help on sending a simple connection to my server socket io?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy. You'll basically have to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) to connect to your backend. The idea is pretty similar to JavaScript applications.

In case you need it, I already implemented a [simple application](https://github.com/danielccunha/socket-io-message) using it on Flutter. It's pretty straightforward and you only have to focus on `mobile/lib/config/socket.dart` which is my socket client.

It contains three simple methods used to emit events and subscribe/unsubscribe to events. Any doubts just ask it.

**EDIT:**
In case you have any problem connecting to your backend add [this line](https://github.com/danielccunha/socket-io-message/blob/master/mobile/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L14) to your Android Manifest. I remember I had some problem because of the android version which had cleartext disabled by default.